# How to create a regex for a Notepad++ search over a range of integers in a CSV file rows

Tags: notepad++, regex, range

I have a have CSV file containing entries with ranges like `[12, 22[` that I want to replace with ranges like `[12; 22[`.
What is the regex to use in Notepad++ in this case ?

sample row of my dataset:

```
1,2,[21, 30[,......
4,3,[22, 32[,......
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[\d+\K,(?=\h*\d+\[)`
- Replace with: `:`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[      # open square bracket
\d+     # 1 or more digits
\K      # forget all we have seen until this position
,       # a comma
(?=     # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
  \h*     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \d+     # 1 or more digits
  \[      # open square bracket
)       # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: i added a space between comma and the second value

Comment: for now it is yielding 0 occurences were replaced

Comment: not working for me it returns invalid regular expr

Comment: @Sam: See my update.

Comment: Alright, now it works, and i thank you.